# i can't find "main storyboard file base name" in info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to create a startup page through pure code. I used to delete info "Main storyboard file base name" in plist file, but after updating Xcode, I found that this option is not available in the configuration file. What should I do as a novice? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you now want to delete is the selected line here:

[image]